# Alternative to using smart pointers to bind an rvalue reference to an abstract class

Tags: c++, c++11, arduino, rvalue-reference

**UPDATE**

It turns out parts of the STL can actually be used -- with care due to the severe memory limitations, though. Arduino is a new platform to me, and after seeing lots of posts talking about the lack of support for STL and even [some ports](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus), I simply assumed it couldn't be used.

Now that I know I can use `unique_ptr`, my original question doesn't make any sense anymore. I will leave it here anyway, just in case it's useful to someone.

*------*

I'm creating a C++ class in an Arduino project -- that means STL is not available (e.g., no smart pointers). Currently I have the following:

```
class ntp_client {
public:
  ntp_client(UDP& udp) : udp_(udp) {}

  // ...

private:
  UDP& udp_;
};
```

`UDP` is a base abstract class to other classes such as `WiFiUDP` or `EthernetUDP`. Now my code looks like:

```
WiFiUDP udp;
ntp_client ntp(udp);
```

But, I'd like to be able to do the following as well:

```
ntp_client ntp{WiFiUDP{}};
```

So, I was thinking to add a constructor taking an rvalue reference, but I don't think there is any way to then bind the rvalue reference to a class attribute (since UDP is an abstract class).

Is it possible to do this without using smart pointers or templates?

Comment: I do not see how it would work. What will your `udp_` reference?

Comment: Keeping references as members like that is very dangerous.  If your `WiFiUDP` object goes out of scope before your `ntp_client` object, you'll end up using a dead object.

Comment: As a programmer in C++, you are responsible for the lifetime of your objects.  If you haven't considered lifetime, your program at best accidentally works.  Not all is lost: writing a really simple unique ptr clone is really easy.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Well, this is not "normal" programming. It's for a microcontroller that doesn't even support the STL and with severe memory restrictions. So, the style of programming is quite different.

Comment: As others have said, permanently storing a reference to a temporary makes no sense.  This is what a .clone() method is for.

Comment: Why exactly would you like to be able to do the second version? Why is the first not enough?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to do what you're doing without smart pointers or templates. After doing `ntp_client ntp{WiFiUDP{}};`, the WiFiUDP object will go out of scope and be destructed. You can't catch it with an rvalue reference to a `udp`, because you can't allocate space for it, either as a member or on the heap.

If you really want to do something like that, you either need to let `ntp_client` know how much memory to allocate (by templates), or allocate the `*UDP` elsewhere and store a pointer to it in `ntp_client`. If you only need to use the `udp` object in `ntp_client` then you could add a constructor taking a pointer to a `udp`, which you could call as `ntp_client ntp{new WiFiUDP()};` and add a `delete` in the ntp_client destructor. Alternatively you could implement a simple untemplated `udpsmartpointer` class that implements a reference count around a `udp` pointer and does the `new` and `delete` for you.

Overall, I think the best solution is the one you already have in your code!

Answer (score 1):

I would revisit your design. I would do it like following:

```
class ntp_client {
public:
  template<class UDP_IMPL, ARGS...>
  ntp_client(ARGS&&... args) : udp_(my::make_unique<UDP_IMPL>(std::forward(ARGS)args...))
                               { }

private:
  my::unique_ptr<UDP> udp_ptr;
};
```

Implementation of `my::unique_ptr` and `my::make_unique` is left as an excercise, since it is trivial.

Explanation - do not keep the references to something you do not really want to own. Instead, construct the proper implementation and keep it.

Comment: The OP does not have access to the standard library: *that means STL is not available (e.g., no smart pointers).*

Comment: @NathanOliver, writing `unique_ptr` is really trivial. But I will edit.

Comment: @betabandido, see my latest edit. `unique_ptr` implementation is trivial, especially, if you are not doing a full-fledged standard-conforming implementation.

Comment: Yes, that might be the best thing. Either that or using templates to specialize `ntp_client`. But, there are only 64KB of RAM for instructions. So, I'm trying to avoid templates as much as possible. I don't know... I was just wondering whether there was some other option.

Comment: @betabandido, what's the problem with templates here? If this is the only usage of unique_ptr<> in your program, it will increase the size of it by very miniscule amount.

Comment: Oh, not in your example. I was referring to the case where no smart pointers were used and the whole class was a template. Anyway, as you can see in the update to my question, I can actually use smart pointers after all. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to construct the ntp_client with an r-value reference (i.e. a temporary) you need to give the temporary somewhere to live.

The logical place would be inside the ntp_client, or something derived from it.

This starts to argue for a factory function that makes either an ntp_client with an encapsulated wifi or ethernet UDP, or a reference to one.

> Is it possible to do this without using smart pointers or templates?

yes, but templates make it easier with less typing...

```
#include <utility>

struct UDP {};

struct WiFiUDP : UDP {};
struct EthernetUDP : UDP {};


class ntp_client {
public:
  ntp_client(UDP& udp) : udp_(udp) {}

  // ...

private:
  UDP& udp_;
};

class Wifi_ntp_client : public ntp_client
{
  // take care - the base class reference is initialised before the stored
  // object. You must not use it in the base class constructor
  // or destructor!
  Wifi_ntp_client(WiFiUDP&& w)
    : ntp_client(_store)
    , _store(std::move(w))
  {}

  WiFiUDP _store;
};

class Ethernet_ntp_client : public ntp_client
{
  // take care - the base class reference is initialised before the stored
  // object. You must not use it in the base class constructor
  // or destructor!
  Ethernet_ntp_client(EthernetUDP&& e)
    : ntp_client(_store)
    , _store(std::move(e))
  {}

  EthernetUDP _store;
};

int main()
{
  WiFiUDP a;
  ntp_client aa(a);

  EthernetUDP b;
  ntp_client bb(b);

  Wifi_ntp_client c(WiFiUDP());
  Ethernet_ntp_client d(EthernetUDP());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make part of the interface for `UDP` to have a clone method that creates a copy (of the actual derived class) and return a pointer to the new object, then you can make your constructor take an r-value reference, clone it, and store it in a `UDP *` and make sure to call delete in your destructor.

```
ntp_client(UDP& udp) : udp_(udp.clone()) {}
UDP * udp_ = nullptr;
~ntp_client(){delete udp_;}
```